# Brave Browser: how to modify extenions keyboard shortcuts

Tags: brave

I have been using Brave for a few months now and wanted to modify some of my extensions settings.

The problem is I can't find where extensions keyboard shortcuts are set as it seems to have no dedicated page as in Google Chrome.

Hitting the same keyboard shortcuts I have in Google Chrome helped me use my extensions.

Does it mean I have to change my Google Chrome extensions keyboard shortcuts in Google Chrome to see a change in Brave?

I am not looking for a way to modify Brave built-in keyboard shortcuts.

Brave Browser v75.0.66.101 (66.101).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same issue and found that you can still access it through the `chrome://extensions/shortcuts` URL. Still sucks that there's no link to it from the extensions page, but you could just make a bookmark to it, I guess.

Source: https://community.brave.com/t/keyboard-shortcuts/50069/4

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome! As of today, Krishnaprasad Nayani's answer is also a viable option.

Comment: Note that one can't ***unset*** a shortcut if the extension sets a default. I filed an [issue against Brave](https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/17745), but the behavior is likely an [upstream issue with Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1275357).

Answer (score 4):

You can go to `brave://settings/` or goto "extension" form the hamburger menu. There on the top right you can see settings tab click on it. There you a can see a menu on left side. Select "extensions" there and scroll down a little you can see "keyboard shortcuts" from there you can edit you extension keyboard shortcuts.